# The output of the following C code is T T , why not t t?

Tags: c, macros

The output of the following C code is `T T`, but I think it should  be `t t`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define T t
void main()
{
     char T = 'T';
     printf("\n%c\t%c\n",T,t);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The preprocessor does not perform substitution of any text within quotes, whether they are single quotes or double quotes.

So the character constant `'T'` is unchanged.

From section 6.10.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *9* A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # define identifier  replacement-list  new-line
> ```
>
> defines an object-like macro that causes each subsequent instance of
>   the macro name <sup>171)</sup> to  be  replaced  by  the  replacement  list  of 
>   preprocessing  tokens  that  constitute  the remainder of the
>   directive.  The replacement list is then rescanned for more macro
>   names as specified below.
>
> > 171) Since, by macro-replacement time, **all character constants and
> >     string literals are preprocessing tokens**, not  sequences  possibly 
> >     containing  identifier-like subsequences  (see  5.1.1.2,  translation 
> >     phases),  **they are never scanned for macro names or parameters.**

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** The variable name `T` is subject to MACRO replacement, not the initializer `'T'`.

---

To elaborate, `#define` MACROs cause textual replacements and anything inside the "quotes" (*either `''` or `""`*) are not part of MACRO replacement.

So in essence, try running the preprocessor on your code (example: `gcc -E test.c`) and it looks like

```
 char t = 'T';
 printf("\n%c\t%c\n",t,t);
```

**[Run `gcc -E main.c -o test.txt  && tail -f test.txt` and <kbd>See it online</kbd>](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c99_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMVFUybmxJdmdqZHM)**

which, expectedly, prints the *value* of variable `t`, `T T`.

That said, for a hosted environment, the required signature for `main()` is `int main(void)`, at least.

Comment: don't you mean `T T`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh But the output is T T and not t t.

Comment: @AnjaniKumar: You want to consider pressing the F5-key ... ;-)